# Pycharm ideolog for scrapy

Tags: scrapy, pycharm

I could not find it in Google, so I ask you. How to configure ideolog for scrapy?

Example log:

```
2020-03-12 11:36:07 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.0.0 started (bot: yandex_market)
2020-03-12 11:36:07 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9.10
```

My solution does not work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Spit on the minuses, maybe I'll help someone!

[image]

```
([^\[]+)\s\[([\w\.]+)\]\s([\w]+)\:(.+)
```